# Boy who becomes a cat

Tags: story-identification, books

I think it was a book from the 70s or thereabouts, possibly older . A boy dies and is reincarnated or somehow put into the body of a cat. He is befriended by another cat who looks after him and teaches him how to behave like an actual cat.

That’s not a lot to go on but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Is this ***[Jennie](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/610718.Jennie)*** (1950) by Paul Gallico...?

> This is the story of a young boy called Peter, who is knocked down by a car. To his considerable astonishment, when he recovers, he is not a young boy, but a cat!
>
> Fortunately, he meets Jennie, a cat who had been abandoned by her family when they moved away, who educates him in the wiles of the feline world. Will he stay a cat with Jennie, or return to being a human boy?

[image: Front cover of "Jennie" by Paul Gallico.]

Comment: Dude, that is it!  My wife loves this book and couldn’t remember the name. She sends her massive thanks!

Comment: It is also called The Abandoned. One of my two favorite cat books of all time. The other is Swamp Cat by Jim Kjelgaard.

Comment: We loved this as children, and also the Carbonel series. Carbonel was king of the cats and I remember having them read to me around the same time.